# Relationiship in mongo

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mean-stack, mongoose-schema

I am new to mongo. While making a application i came across a weird requirement. 
I have collection **Document** and **UserData**. The schema for both is given below.

```
Document {
    data : String , 
    id : number,
    lockedBy : Users
}


Users{
    name : String, 
    email : String,
    id : String
}
```

So here basically a user can lock a document for himself and no one can access it.

The problem here is i dont want to save entire user data in the Document as it will create a lot of redundant data. I want to save the id of the user.

But on the ui side the requirement is to give entire user object(containing id , name , email) as the value of lockedBy.

What I do is i save lockedBy as string with the id of user. Then while fetching i replace the lockedBy with user data by making another call to database and getting the user data based on id.

With increasing number of fetching and saving api i have to make transformation in lot of places. Is there any way to this in a different way. Where i dont have to write the transformation code for lockedBy to change is string to UserData and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

keep user_id in the Schema,

while sending the response object add users in it, by retrieving it from the the db.

Comment: But that would make two calls to the database and i want to avoid that